# compilation error while creating pair of long and vector in c++

Tags: c++

How can i make a pair of long and a vector in c++? Following give me syntax error and i don't understand the reason?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  make_pair<int,vector<long> > lvp;
}
```

That results in this error:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 pair_vector.cpp

pair_vector.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:

pair_vector.cpp:6:32: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘lvp’
   make_pair<int,vector<long> > lvp;
                                ^
```

Comment: `std::make_pair` is a function... Please read the documentation again.

Comment: Your variable needs a *type* which would be `std::pair<int,vector<long>>`. `std::make_pair` is a function, you can not declare a variable using that.

Comment: Code that is already uncompilable for unrelated reasons and no attention to the documentation does not a good question make. I have voted to close this as being caused by a simple typographical error.

Comment: @user2079303 comment clarified... I was referring to the missing leading `#`, the lack of a return type, etc.

Comment: @underscore_d oh, right. Unrelated compilation errors are bad for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`make_pair` is a function, so you'd use it something like:

```
auto lvp = std::make_pair(1, std::vector<long>{ 1, 2, 3, 4 });
```

The syntax you have would fit with just using `std::pair`:

```
std::pair<int,vector<long> > lvp;
```

Note that starting with C++ 11, you no longer need to put a space between the angle brackets to prevent mis-parsing either, so you could use:

```
std::pair<int,vector<long>> lvp;
```

...if you preferred.